# How to apply some changes to all remote git branch

Tags: java, git

There are two git branch names: 1- master 2- develop. In order to these remote branches, there are two local branches as same as remote branches.

I changed some changes **(file1, file2, file3)** in local-develop branch and pushed to remote-develop branch, so I want to apply some of these changes **(file1, file2)** to master branch too.
 
How do I do?

Comment: First Checkout to the master branch
and do merge accordingly

Answer (score 1):

you only need to merge your branch develop to master

from branch develop
switch to branch master

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned steps:

1. copy commit hash what you get after commit into develop.
2. git checkout master.
3. git cherry-pick
4. git reset --mixed head~1
5. git reset file3
6. git commit -m "your commit into master"

Use **git reset file** for what file you don't want to commit into master.

Comment: just do checkout as git checkout <<branchname>>
do merge : git merge <<branch_to_be_merge>>
do commit : git commit -m "YOUR_COMMIT_MESSAGE"
do push : git push

Comment: So above mentioned steps are for merge commit partially. And that's what I think he wants.